# Cannot Set Up Samsung Default Email and Add CenturyLink.net Account

Tags: email, pop3

Samsung Galaxy S9 phone

Until recently I could send/receive emails on my phone with the Samsung default email app with an email address at centurylink.net.

I had a problem with my centurylink.net email and a Samsung support person told me to go into the Mail app and Delete Data, and then I would just have to log in again.  However, I have not been able to Set Up Email and Add Account.

I get “Couldn’t verify account
The username or password is incorrect or POP3/IMAP access isn’t turned on for this account.  Check your email account setting on the web, then try again.”

I have confirmed that I have entered my full email address and password correctly (Show password).  I can log onto centurylink.net with them on my phone with a browser.

Samsung support says talk to my email provider and Centurylink support says to talk to Samsung.  I have gone through this loop 3 times, but still have the problem.

I have also searched online for a solution, but found none.

I am using these parameters, as Centurylink says to use at
https://www.centurylink.com/home/help/internet/email/setup-email-on-android-device.html

Domains centurylink.net

Incoming Server (choose one)    POP: pop.centurylink.net, Port: 995, Security: SSL

Outgoing Server SMTP: smtp.centurylink.net, Port 587 TLS

Username    Full Email Address

Comment: Are you sure you want to use POP3? Nowadays most people use IMAP instead of POP3 as on IMAP the mails stay on the server, instead of POP3 which downloads the mails and deletes them on the server. Therefore my recommendation is to use IMAP instead. What is the error message you get? Please screenshots of the settings pages of Samsung Mail so we can see what you have configured.